# What function parameters should be used for sdl2.SDL_GetWindowSize?

Tags: python, sdl-2

I would like to know what is the appropriate way to use `SDL_GetWindowSize()`. According to the error msg I got, I should not use WIDTH and HEIGHT as they are integers. So what should be use in their places?

```
import sdl2

APP_SHORT_NAME = 'Test'
WIDTH = 400
HEIGHT = 400

sdl2.SDL_Init(sdl2.SDL_INIT_VIDEO)
window = sdl2.SDL_CreateWindow(
    APP_SHORT_NAME.encode('ascii'),
    sdl2.SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, sdl2.SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
    WIDTH, HEIGHT, 0 )

sdlWindowsize = sdl2.SDL_GetWindowSize( window, WIDTH, HEIGHT )
print('sdlWindowsize = {0}'.format(sdlWindowsize))
```

Error msg:

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "/home/sunbear/Coding/Vulkan/vulkan/MyProject/LunarG_cube_example/sdl2_window.py", line 13, in <module>
    sdlWindowsize = sdl2.SDL_GetWindowSize( window, WIDTH, HEIGHT )
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 2: <class 'TypeError'>: expected LP_c_int instance instead of int
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

[SDL_GetWindowSize](https://wiki.libsdl.org/SDL_GetWindowSize) expects 3 parameters - window, and two pointers to `int` where it will save resulting values. It doesn't return any value. As pysdl2 uses ctypes, it should be e.g.:

```
import sdl2
import ctypes

APP_SHORT_NAME = 'Test'
WIDTH = 400
HEIGHT = 400

sdl2.SDL_Init(sdl2.SDL_INIT_VIDEO)
window = sdl2.SDL_CreateWindow(
    APP_SHORT_NAME.encode('ascii'),
    sdl2.SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED, sdl2.SDL_WINDOWPOS_UNDEFINED,
    WIDTH, HEIGHT, 0 )

w = ctypes.c_int()
h = ctypes.c_int()
sdl2.SDL_GetWindowSize( window, w, h)
print("w=%d h=%d" % (w.value, h.value))
```

Comment: Should it be `w = ctypes.c_int()` and `h = ctypes.c_int()` instead? I tried these and they worked too. Using `w = ctypes.c_int(WIDTH)` and `h = ctypes.c_int(HEIGHT)` gave the impression that WIDTH and HEIGHT was needed to be passed in to SDL_GetWindowSize() to get the width and height of the window, which seem strange.

Comment: That's right, it is just the intial value. Doesn't matter in that case. But yes, it is probably better to initialise it to 0 instead.